# Wikidata "Truthy" data dump

Tags: rdf, wikidata

I'm starting a project on knowledge bases and wanted to start by downloading a recent dump of Wikidata. I found a data dump called "truthy", but I am not sure if I can trust it.

My understanding from pop culture is that a "truthy" statement is one that is **not** true and [based only on intuition and perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness). Thanks, Mr. Colbert.

Why would Wikidata produce a "truthy" data dump where the data is not accurate?

What's also confusing is that there are conflicting definitions. For example, here is the [definition of "truthy" data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format) directly from the WikiMedia organization:

> Truthy statements represent statements that have the best
>   non-deprecated rank for given property. Namely, if there is a
>   preferred statement for property P2, then only preferred statements
>   for P2 will be considered truthy.

To me, that quote means that a truthy statement (fact triple) is the preferred one.

This [other webpage](https://lod-cloud.net/dataset/wikidata) says this about "truthy":

> This contains only “truthy” or “best” statements, without qualifiers or references.

What am I got make of this? Is this "truthy" data reliable and believable or not?

Comment: I hope you'll get a good answer here but I'd suggest asking it at the [Wikidata chat](https://t.me/joinchat/AZriqUj5UagVMHXYzfZFvA) as well. By the way I recently stumbled upon [this article](https://addshore.com/2019/10/your-own-wikidata-query-service-with-no-limits-part-1/) which might be of interest. And last, let's not forget that Wikidata is a collection of claims, and having references does not change the nature of the statements.

Comment: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Yes, I already quoted that in my post: `Truthy statements represent statements that have the best non-deprecated rank for given property`. But does that mean it's truthful? That would conflict with `truthiness` from the Colbert Report.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov: That "Wikidata chat" link points to an app called Telegram. I don't want to install stuff. Do you know if there's a definitive message board forum for Wikidata? I already searched online but couldn't find one.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 this is more an aside, but Colbert's definition does not say that a "truthy" statement is definitely false, it just says it is asserted as true without anything rational/logical/factual to back that up. It might be true, it might be false, we don't really know.

Comment: ```Truthy``` In a programming context generally refers to values that are distinct from the actual value ```TRUE``` of type ```Boolean```, but are considered to be ```true``` when used in situation where a boolean value is asked for (i. e. if statements). Examples are positive numbers (negative being ```falsy```), strings of length > 0, etc. Wikidata's usage is related to this.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 The Wikidata Project chat is the definitive message board for Wikidata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Wikidata, each [statement](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Statements) has an associated [rank](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking): preferred rank, normal rank, deprecated rank. The default value is normal rank but everybody (registered and anonymous users) can change the rank to one of the other values. There are no rules enforced how to assign the ranks. Generally, deprecated rank is used for proven faults. Preferred rank is often used for the most up-to-date value in time series.

The "truthy" data dump does not contain any statements with deprecated rank and if there are statements with normal and preferred rank, only the statements with preferred rank are in the dump.

If you want to get in touch with the Wikidata community, go to the [Wikidata project chat](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat). If you prefer to communicate directly with the developpers of Wikidata/Wikibase, go to [this page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Contact_the_development_team).