# Querying for a country Speed limits

Tags: sparql, wikidata-api

I'm trying to get a list of general speed limits for a given country from WikiData using SPARQLE.

For example France:

```
SELECT ?speed ?qualifierLabel WHERE {
    wd:Q142
        wdt:P3086 ?speed ;
       p:P3086 [
            ps:P3086 ?speed ;
            pq:P3005 ?qualifier ;
        ] . 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

This gives me [1 result](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fspeed%20%3FqualifierLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ142%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP3086%20%3Fspeed%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%3AP3086%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ps%3AP3086%20%3Fspeed%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pq%3AP3005%20%3Fqualifier%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D). The [web page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q142) knows 6 speed limits.
For Germany (Q183) the same query gives me 2 results, the web page knows 3.

What's the problem here?

**Update:**
UninformedUser has solved half of the problem, the info for France can be queried now. But for Germany this doesn't work 100%:

```
SELECT ?speed ?qualifierLabel WHERE {
    wd:Q183
       p:P3086 [
            ps:P3086 ?speed ;
            pq:P3005 ?qualifier ;
        ] . 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

You get only [2 results](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fspeed%20%3FqualifierLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ183%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%3AP3086%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ps%3AP3086%20%3Fspeed%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pq%3AP3005%20%3Fqualifier%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D), while the [web page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q183) lists 3. (Maybe because one of the results is "no value"? Is that filtered out?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627558/wikidata-truthy-data-dump - you mixed up the way how to query i) only truthy data and ii) all data, a join on `?speed` prevents all 6 results. Long story short, remove  `wdt:P3086 ?speed ;`

Comment: @UninformedUser: Thanks, you're right, that gets me all 6 results for France. But for Germany I still get only 2 of the 3 results. Do know the secret for this, too?

Comment: BTW, do you know a good page that explains the SPARQL  syntax? I tried to understand the Wikidata:SPARQL tutorial, but it only confuses me.